# Does difficulty matter?

Tags: prinny-2

In Prinny 2: Dawn of Operation Panties, Dood! does the difficulty affect anything other than difficulty and which scoreboard you're ranked on? E.G. does it change the ending or make any events more/less likely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough I found the answer to this on accident while looking up what in the world this was. From the [Destructoid Review of the game](http://www.destructoid.com/review-prinny-2-dawn-of-operation-panties-dood--191194.phtml):

> [Note: I played most of Prinny 2 on the easiest difficulty, as the harder difficulties offer no special rewards or unlockables. I would recommend that most of you do the same, as my time with the the harder difficulties added nothing to my experience but additional frustration.]

Comment: I don't agree with the author that the game is just as fun in super-easy mode, but I thought I'd rush through to unlock everything in easy first and save myself some grief if there wasn't any benefit.